# Sort pandas df subset of rows (within a group) by specific column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have the following dataframe let’s say:

df

```
A B C D E
z k s 7 d
z k s 6 l
x t r 2 e
x t r 1 x
u c r 8 f
u c r 9 h
y t s 5 l
y t s 2 o
```

And I would like to sort it based on col D for each sub row (that has for example same cols A,B and C in this case)

The expected output would be:

df

```
A B C D E
z k s 6 l
z k s 7 d
x t r 1 x
x t r 2 e
u c r 8 f
u c r 9 h
y t s 2 o
y t s 5 l
```

Any help for this kind of operation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it should be as simple as this:

```py
df = df.sort_values(["A", "B", "C", "D"])
```

Comment: This will not work , cause it will sort the column A first

Comment: @BENY I'm not sure why is that.

Comment: This works for this use case; however, I am not sure if it works for sorting within groups, as this just sorts based on the entire dataframe

Comment: I realize it's not intuitive, and I honestly haven't even tested it with the given example. But, do you have a counter-example that this doesn't work for?

Answer (score 2):

You can use groupby and sort values (also credit to @Henry Ecker for his comment):

```
df.groupby(['A','B','C'],group_keys=False,sort=False).apply(pd.DataFrame.sort_values,'D')
```

output:

```
    A   B   C   D   E
1   z   k   s   6   l
0   z   k   s   7   d
3   x   t   r   1   x
2   x   t   r   2   e
4   u   c   r   8   f
5   u   c   r   9   h
7   y   t   s   2   o
6   y   t   s   5   l
```

Comment: This changes the association with column E (was 6L/7D, but becomes 6D/7L for the first set)

Comment: when you use `.transform(lambda x: x.sort_values())` why is the index ignored? I would think that while the operation is performed, when the series is reconstructed, applying this function would have no effect.

Comment: `transform` operations are specifically unaligned ("the same indexes as the original object filled with the transformed values") [src](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html). That is the reason to choose this operation over others. @rhug123

Comment: @Randy Thank you for the catch. Edited the answer.

Comment: Oops. You're absolutely correct, it was hard to tell with the ordering difference. How about throwing a `sort=False` as well in the groupby to match OP's output: `df.groupby(['A','B','C'], group_keys=False, sort=False).apply(pd.DataFrame.sort_values, 'D')`?

Comment: @HenryEcker Did not think the order of groups to be important, but why not. Adding your comment to the answer. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks!, this solution worked for me as well! Same result of @Saed SayedAhmed' solution

Answer (score 2):

Let us try `ngroup` create the help col

```
df['new1'] = df.groupby(['A','B','C'],sort=False).ngroup()
df = df.sort_values(['new1','D']).drop('new1',axis=1)
df
   A  B  C  D  E
1  z  k  s  6  l
0  z  k  s  7  d
3  x  t  r  1  x
2  x  t  r  2  e
4  u  c  r  8  f
5  u  c  r  9  h
7  y  t  s  2  o
6  y  t  s  5  l
```

Answer (score 1):

```
dic = {
    'A': [*'zzxxuuyy'],
    'B': [*'kkttcctt'],
    'C': [*'ssrrrrss'],
    'D': [*map(int, '76218952')],
    'E': [*'dlexfhlo']
}
df = pd.DataFrame(dic)
```

```
df.groupby(['A', 'B']).apply(lambda df: df.sort_values('D')).droplevel(['A', 'B']).reset_index()
```

if you want to sort based on columns 'A', 'B', 'C', 'E' then you have to:

```
df.groupby(['A', 'B', 'D', 'E']).apply(lambda df: df.sort_values('D')).droplevel(['A', 'B', 'D', 'E']).reset_index()
```